# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript

И в чем вообще проблема данного кода? Не работает

```
srcs = [ "upload/iphone.png", "upload/screen.png" ]
###
setInterval(
function() 
{ 
    $('.image1').fadeOut(300, function()
    { 
        $(this).attr('src',srcs[Math.floor(Math.random()*srcs.length)];).bind('onreadystatechange load', 
        function()
        { 
            if (this.complete) $(this).fadeIn(300); 
        }); 
    }); 
}), 5000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Math.floor(Math.random()*srcs.length)];` убрать `;`
`}), 5000);` - убрать первые скобки `)`

Ваш редактор не подсвечивает ошибки?
Я просто не совсем понимаю, в чем сложность возникла найти ошибку?